# Google visualization Combo Chart with image or text instead of Pointshape

Tags: asp.net, charts, google-visualization

Following is Code to draw lines that form rectangle inside google chart,

How to have pointshape with text or custom image  in google combo chart  as shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOouf.png)?

Below is code I have written.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['FirstLine_X', 'FirstLine_Y','SecondLine_Y','SecondLine_X',{'type': 'string', 'role': 'style'},{ role: 'annotation' }],
[7,5,null,null,null,null],
[7,0,null,null,null,null],
[3.5,0,null,null,null,null],
[3.5,5,null,null,null,null],
[7,5,null,null,null,null],
[1.5,null,0,null,null,null],
[1.5,null,10,null,null,null],
[10.5,null,10,null,null,null],
[10.5,null,0,null,null,null],
[7,null,0,null,null,null],
[7,null,5,null,null,null],
[3.5,null,5,null,null,null],
[3.5,null,0,null,null,null],
[1.5,null,0,null,null,null],
[10,null,null,5,'point { size: 3; shape-type: star; fill-color: #a52714; }','First Point'],
[8,null,null,5,'point { size: 3; shape-type: none; fill-color: green; }','Second Point']
]);
```

I want something like below where custom images are used while drawing the chart.

```
var options = {
          legend: 'none',
          hAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 7 },
          pointSize: 30,
          series: {
                0: { pointShape: '1.png' },
                1: { pointShape: '2.png' },
                2: { pointShape: 'abc.png' },
                3: { pointShape: 'x.png' },
                4: { pointShape: 'star.png' },
                5: { pointShape: 'p.png' }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Many of your questions are badly explained and do not fit the SO guidelines. Please read **all** of the [help]

Comment: you can use the `getChartLayoutInterface` [method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#methods) to find the (x, y) location of the point and add the image manually -- see this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39553121/5090771)